# Axios: Content-Length header is missing on request headers

Tags: node.js, axios, content-length

we are facing an issue in production that the 'Content-Length' header is not being sent, even if we hard-code it in the headers properties, so we are receiving back from the server the 411 Length Required error.

We are using:

- Axios 0.16.2
- NodeJS 6.10
- Application deployed inside AWS Lambda environment

The code that is causing the issue is the following:

```
let cookieJar;
const postBody = "MyBody=MyBodyContentGoesHere";
const url = "https://my-url.com";
return axios
        .post(url,
            postBody,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                timeout: 10000,
                jar: cookieJar,
                withCredentials: true
            }
        );
```

I wrote an application in .NET and the header is sent properly (without to pass it manually). This .NET application was written just to test, it's not the real application.

Do you have some idea?
I open a issue in the axios github project, but I want to know from you guys some ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a "data" field to the config object?

```
let cookieJar;
const postBody = "MyBody=MyBodyContentGoesHere";
const url = "https://my-url.com";
return axios
    .post(url,
        postBody,
        {
            data: postBody,
             headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            timeout: 10000,
            jar: cookieJar,
            withCredentials: true
        }
    );
```

Comment: Seems redundant.  Why do you think it might help?

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue as you. Using `querystring` as suggested in [the offical docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#nodejs) solved it for me.

```
'use strict';

let querystring = require('querystring');

let cookieJar;
const postBody = querystring.stringify({ MyBody: 'MyBodyContentGoesHere' });
const url = 'https://my-url.com';
return axios.post(url, postBody, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    timeout: 10000,
    jar: cookieJar,
    withCredentials: true
  }
);
```